# silverlight webbrowser control InvokeScript error

Tags: javascript, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, browser

I am running OOB silverlight application where I have a `WebBrowser` control but I am getting this error when I call `InvokeScript`:-

> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

Is it because it's OOB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it can't be because its OOB since `WebBrowser` only works OOB anyway.   I can think of two possible reasons.

- The Url to which the WebBrowser has navigated is not on the same site from with the Silverlight application has been loaded.  This would a security violation.
- The code that is being executed in the loaded web page by the `InvokeScript` is the actual source of the error.

Comment: About the second reason, the JS function has no errors. but i can't understand the first reason. sorry for getting it long on u but i can't find anything about this error online :S that's wired looks like it only happens to me  :D

Comment: Do u wanna say that i can't access any functions except if i was browsing the site which the application was downloaded from ??!!!!

Comment: @Miroo:  Yes that is exacly what I'm saying.  You cannot call JS functions in a page that comes from a different site than you Silverlight application.  This would constitute a cross-domain scripting breach which could endanger the users privacy or worse their bank account.

Comment: well i found a param that called EnableHTMLAccess must be set to True, but i can't understand where should i have it, in the silverlight object ??!!! how come while i am running my application OOB i am not even debugging through the web page :s

Comment: @Miroo:  EnableHTMLAccess is placed on the object tag when a silverlight application is embedded in a web page, it isn't relevant to your case.  An OOB runs "out of browser" so clearly it isn't going to debug through the web page.

Comment: Dear antony, Thanks too much, it worked fine when i installed it to my machine, i was testing it from VS debug :)